# Saxon implementation for Stream of data

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon

In my code below, I’m modifying the XML file with XSLT using SAXON

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class SaxonImplementation {

  public static void simpleTransform(String sourcePath, String xsltPath,
      String resultDir) {
    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    try {
      Transformer transformer = tFactory
          .newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File(xsltPath)));
      transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new File(sourcePath)),
          new StreamResult(new File(resultDir)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory",
        "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");
    simpleTransform("first.xml", "newxsl.xslt", "second.xml");
  }
}
```

Now instead of modifying the XML file, I want to modify an XML string. How shall I proceed here? 
The transformer.transform method requires an XML source file and the result file. How can I provide an XML string instead of a file and get the results in the form of Stream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `StreamSource` for a `java.io.Reader` therefore wrap the XML string in a `StringReader` and then in a `StreamSource` and pass that to the transformer:

```
String xml = ...
transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml)), ...
```

Same is true for the `StreamResult`, you can use any `OutputStream` or `Writer` to create a `StreamResult`.

And this works for any `Trax` implementation not just for Saxon.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer :) . I will try to do as you have mentioned.